# Returns all jpg images from a directory in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am tring to returns all jpg images from a directory in an array. Below are my code.

```
package component;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static ArrayList<String> getAllImages(File directory, boolean descendIntoSubDirectories) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(256);
    File[] f = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : f) {
        if (file != null && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") && !file.getName().startsWith("tn_")) {
            resultList.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
        }
        if (descendIntoSubDirectories && file.isDirectory()) {
            ArrayList<String> tmp = getAllImages(file, true);
            if (tmp != null) {
                resultList.addAll(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    if (resultList.size() > 0)
        return resultList;
    else
        return null;
}


}
```

I run this code but unfortunately i got this error message. Can i know what is wrong with my code?Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: try increasing the maxheap

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use same list for each function call. Here you creates a new list for each function call. Also, you can initialise list without giving size.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllImages(File directory, boolean descendIntoSubDirectories) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    getAllImagesHelper(directory, descendIntoSubDirectories, results);

    return results;
}

public static void getAllImagesHelper(File directory, boolean descendIntoSubDirectories, ArrayList<String> results) throws IOException {
    File[] f = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : f) {
        if (file != null && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") && !file.getName().startsWith("tn_")) {
            results.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
        }
        if (descendIntoSubDirectories && file.isDirectory()) {
            getAllImagesHelper(file, true, results);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use following code if you just want all .jpg Files from a directory (without subDirectries)

```
Files.list(Paths.get("yourPath")).filter(path->Files.isRegularFile(path) && path.toString().endsWith(".jpg")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you need subdirectories:

```
List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    Path start = Paths.get("yourPath");
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path filePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (filePath.toString().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    paths.add(filePath);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```